# Example of php query strings updating html img src using GET?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, query-string

I have a site, www.example.com/index.html

It has two text input fields for users to paste img/gif urls

Clicking a submit button uses javascript to create a div with an img tag in it in my html file and it also converts the user input value into the div's img's src.

How would the submit button also update the site url to example.com/index.html?gif=someurl.com&gif2=someurl2.com

This way the user could copy and paste the url with query parameters and share it with someone and when that someone click the link, they're brought to the site, both of the divs would have img src's automatically loaded.

Comment: Put form method to get.

Comment: `example.com/index.html?gif=nastypornsite.com/hideously_illegal_picture.gif` -- that'll go over well in little bobby's christmas email to grandma.

Comment: in PHP: check if $_GET['gif'] is set and set the div's img's src to that value. And if its not set, dont do anything. But I would pay attention to what Marc B wrote

Comment: I'll give that a try thank you. But I don't understand Marc B's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the url dynamically unless you have a hash in it (like example.com/index.html#gif=someurl.com&gif2=someurl2.com).

Here's an example of how you would do it with a hash:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var imgArray = window.location.hash.split("&gif=");

    for(var i=0; i<imgArray.length; i++) {
        $("#imgDiv").append($("<img>").attr("src", imgArray[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this jsfiddle isn't working but it's basically what I have working on my site right now. Submit button updates img src and so would I combine your code with what I have or replace it? http://jsfiddle.net/DsZVT/

Comment: I can't answer that because I don't know what your code looks like

Answer (score 0):

It is not a "php query string".
It is URL with params, not strictly related to PHP or any other backend language.

If you will change the url via:

```
window.location = 'url';
```

The browser will navigate to the new page.

I recommend updating URL hash with

```
window.location.hash = 'url';
```

The at the beggining of your javascript, check if hash matches the pattern and contains a properties of the image file. The execute your function which shows IMG with the values.